# How do I mock part of a python constructor just for testing?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-mock

I am new to Python, so I apologize if this is a duplicate or overly simple question. I have written a coordinator class that calls two other classes that use the kafka-python library to send/read data from Kafka. I want to write a unit test for my coordinator class but I'm having trouble figuring out how to best to go about this. I was hoping that I could make an alternate constructor that I could pass my mocked objects into, but this doesn't seem to be working as I get an error that test_mycoordinator cannot be resolved. Am I going about testing this class the wrong way? Is there a pythonic way I should be testing it?

Here is what my test class looks like so far:

```
import unittest
from mock import Mock
from mypackage import mycoordinator

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUpModule(self):
        # Create a mock producer
        producer_attributes = ['__init__', 'run', 'stop']
        mock_producer = Mock(name='Producer', spec=producer_attributes)

        # Create a mock consumer
        consumer_attributes = ['__init__', 'run', 'stop']
        data_out = [{u'dataObjectID': u'test1'},
                    {u'dataObjectID': u'test2'},
                    {u'dataObjectID': u'test3'}]
        mock_consumer = Mock(
            name='Consumer', spec=consumer_attributes, return_value=data_out)

        self.coor = mycoordinator.test_mycoordinator(mock_producer, mock_consumer)

    def test_send_data(self):
        # Create some data and send it to the producer
        count = 0
        while count < 3:
            count += 1
            testName = 'test' + str(count)
            self.coor.sendData(testName , None)
```

And here is the class I am trying to test:

```
class MyCoordinator():
    def __init__(self):
        # Process Command Line Arguments using argparse  
        ...

        # Initialize the producer and the consumer
        self.myproducer = producer.Producer(self.servers,
                                            self.producer_topic_name)

        self.myconsumer = consumer.Consumer(self.servers,
                                            self.consumer_topic_name)

    # Constructor used for testing -- DOES NOT WORK
    @classmethod
    def test_mycoordinator(cls, mock_producer, mock_consumer):
        cls.myproducer = mock_producer
        cls.myconsumer = mock_consumer

    # Send the data to the producer
    def sendData(self, data, key):
        self.myproducer.run(data, key)

    # Receive data from the consumer
    def getData(self):
        data = self.myconsumer.run()
        return data
```

Comment: wher edoes `mycordinator` come from in your `setUpModule`?

Comment: @dm03514 sorry, I had a typo when I was changing the names I've edited the question to fix the import statement

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There is no need to provide a separate constructor. Mocking *patches your code* to replace objects with mocks. Just use the [`mock.patch()` decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) on your test methods; it'll pass in references to the generated mock objects.

Both `producer.Producer()` and `consumer.Consumer()` are then mocked out *before* you create the instance:

```
import mock

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('producer.Producer', autospec=True)
    @mock.patch('consumer.Consumer', autospec=True)
    def test_send_data(self, mock_consumer, mock_producer):
        # configure the consumer instance run method
        consumer_instance = mock_consumer.return_value
        consumer_instance.run.return_value = [
            {u'dataObjectID': u'test1'},
            {u'dataObjectID': u'test2'},
            {u'dataObjectID': u'test3'}]

        coor = MyCoordinator()
        # Create some data and send it to the producer
        for count in range(3):
            coor.sendData('test{}'.format(count) , None)

        # Now verify that the mocks have been called correctly
        mock_producer.assert_has_calls([
            mock.Call('test1', None),
            mock.Call('test2', None),
            mock.Call('test3', None)])
```

So the moment `test_send_data` is called, the `mock.patch()` code replaces the `producer.Producer` reference with a mock object. Your `MyCoordinator` class then uses those mock objects rather than the real code. calling `producer.Producer()` returns a new mock object (the same object that `mock_producer.return_value` references), etc.

I've made the assumption that `producer` and `consumer` are top-level module names. If they are not, provide the full import path. From the `mock.patch()` documentation:

> *target* should be a string in the form `'package.module.ClassName'`. The target is imported and the specified object replaced with the new object, so the target must be importable from the environment you are calling `patch()` from. The target is imported when the decorated function is executed, not at decoration time.

Comment: How does @mock.patch('consumer.Consumer', autospec=True) mock the consumer class I wrote? More specifically how does it know what I want mocked? I'm seeing an error when I try and run the test (ImportError: No module named consumer). My class Consumer is in consumer.py which is in mypackage. So do I need to specify the full path to the Consumer class in the patch somehow?

Comment: @jencoston: You didn't include where `consumer` came from in your code; I made the assumption that that was the name of the module. If `consumer` is inside a package, provide the full name of the import: `mock.patch('package.consumer.Consumer')`. `mock.patch` will import the module and patch the name (last part of the path).

Comment: @MartijnPieters would you please comment about a gotcha: I believe that the class usage must match the mock *exactly*. The code here uses `myconsumer = consumer.Consumer()` and the mock has `consumer.Consumer` so that's a match. In my code I tried instead something like `from myconsumer import Consumer` and `myconsumer = Consumer()` which does *not* match `consumer.Consumer` in the mock. I don't have the experience with `unittest.mock` to explain why. Thx in adv!

Comment: @chrisinmtown: see the [*Where to patch* section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch); you need to patch `yourmodule.Consumer` in that case.