# How to mock a constructor called in a parent class while testing a child class using Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I'm trying to mock an object that makes some expensive network calls when it's initialized, but the parent class instantiating it isn't recognizing the patch from my unit test.

Some similar questions I've already looked at:

- [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43354242/14765128) Doesn't involve any inheritance like in my current situation.
- [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61002944/14765128) Has a similar inheritance structure, but it mocks a method instead of a constructor.

#### Minimal Reproducible Example [3](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

###### File Structure

```
--src
   |-- resource.py
   |-- family.py
   |-- test_child.py
```

###### resource.py

```py
class Resource:

    def __init__(self):
        print("Expensive network call")

    def use_resource(self) -> str:
        print("Another expensive network call")
        return "bar"
```

###### family.py

```py
from resource import Resource

class Parent:

    def __init__(self):
        print("In the Parent constructor.")
        self.resource = Resource()

    def foo(self):
        print("Parent's foo")
        print(self.resource.use_resource())

class Child(Parent):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("In the Child constructor")
    
    def foo(self):
        print("Child's foo")
        super().foo()
```

###### test_child.py

```py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

from family import Child

class TestChild(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('resource.Resource')
    def test_foo(self, mock_resource):
        mock_resource.return_value.use_resource.return_value = "mock_bar"
        child = Child()
        child.foo()
        mock_resource.return_value.use_resource.assert_called_once()

unittest.main()
```

### Expected Result

Since I'm patching `resource.Resource`, I'm expecting to avoid the expensive network calls that normally occur when a `Parent` instantiates a `Resource`. Theoretically the output of running `test_child.py` should look like this:

```
In the Parent constructor.
In the Child constructor
Child's foo
Parent's foo
mock_bar
```

### Actual Result

However, despite patching `resource.Resource` in the test, the `Parent` is still instantiating an actual `Resource` as evidenced by the presence of the "Expensive network call" messages in the output and the failed `assert_called_once` assertion.

```
In the Parent constructor.
Expensive network call           # Should have been patched
In the Child constructor
Child's foo
Parent's foo
Another expensive network call   # Should have been patched
bar                              # Should have been patched
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_foo (__main__.TestChild)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[REMOVED]\unittest\mock.py", line 1342, in patched
    return func(*newargs, **newkeywargs)
  File "[REMOVED]\test_child.py", line 13, in test_foo
    mock_resource.return_value.use_resource.assert_called_once()
  File "[REMOVED]\unittest\mock.py", line 886, in assert_called_once
    raise AssertionError(msg)
AssertionError: Expected 'use_resource' to have been called once. Called 0 times.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.005s
```

### What do I need to change so that `Parent`'s instantiation of a `Resource` uses a mocked `Resource` instead of an actual `Resource`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use `@patch(family.Resource)` instead of `@patch(resource.Resource)`

There are two key ideas that explain why your patch failed:

1. When your `Parent` class instantiates a `Resource`, it is not directly instantiating a `resource.Resource`, rather it is instantiating the `family` module's *import* of a `Resource`.
2. While your `family` module does import `resource.Resource` (which you are indeed patching), that import occurs *prior* to your patch because you import the `family` module prior to executing the patch.

See the [unittest.mock documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch) if you want more details. This [article from Medium](https://yeraydiazdiaz.medium.com/what-the-mock-cheatsheet-mocking-in-python-6a71db997832#1a30) is also really helpful for understanding the oddities of mocking in Python.

---

#### Demonstration

For completeness, here's your `test_child.py` with the correction...

```py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

from family import Child


class TestChild(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('family.Resource')  # Changed this line
    def test_foo(self, mock_resource):
        mock_resource.return_value.use_resource.return_value = "mock_bar"
        # Alternatively, move `from family import Child` here.
        child = Child()
        child.foo()
        mock_resource.return_value.use_resource.assert_called_once()

unittest.main()
```

... and the test output matches the expected output in your question.

```
In the Parent constructor.
In the Child constructor
Child's foo
Parent's foo
mock_bar
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.004s

OK
```