# How do I mock the pymysqlpool.ConnectionPool constructor?

Tags: python, testing, mocking

Similar to [How do I mock part of a python constructor just for testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43354242/how-do-i-mock-part-of-a-python-constructor-just-for-testing) but explicitly trying to get `pymysqlpool.ConnectionPool` to work/

```
class DbTests(TestCase):
    @mock.patch('pymysqlpool.ConnectionPool', autospec=True)
    @mock.patch.dict(
        os.environ,
        {
            "DATASOURCES_0_SERVERID": "server1",
            "DATASOURCES_0_HOST": "non-existent",
            "DATASOURCES_0_PORT": "3307",
            "DATASOURCES_0_DATABASE": "lj_ca1",
            "DATASOURCES_0_USERNAME": "sampleuser",
            "DATASOURCES_0_PASSWORD": "password1",
            "DATASOURCES_0_TIMEZONE": "Americas/Toronto",
        },
    )    
    def test_load(self, connection_pool_mock: mock.Mock):
        ConnectionPool(
            size=2, maxsize=3, pre_create_num=2, host=os.environ["DATASOURCES_0_HOST"]
        )
```

I'm expecting the code to simply work, but I am getting

> pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'non-existent' ([Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed)")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that in your test file you have the following import:

```
from pymysqlpool import ConnectionPool
```

This defines the name `ConnectionPool` in the test module, but your instruction `patch('pymysqlpool.ConnectionPool')` substitutes the object points by the name `pymysqlpool.ConnectionPool` so it operates on an other name.

The import in your test code must change to:

```
import pymysqlpool
```

So your test code becomes:

```
import pymysqlpool
from unittest import TestCase, mock

class DbTests(TestCase):
    @mock.patch('pymysqlpool.ConnectionPool', autospec=True)
    @mock.patch.dict(
        os.environ,
        {
            "DATASOURCES_0_SERVERID": "server1",
            "DATASOURCES_0_HOST": "non-existent",
            "DATASOURCES_0_PORT": "3307",
            "DATASOURCES_0_DATABASE": "lj_ca1",
            "DATASOURCES_0_USERNAME": "sampleuser",
            "DATASOURCES_0_PASSWORD": "password1",
            "DATASOURCES_0_TIMEZONE": "Americas/Toronto",
        },
    )    
    def test_load(self, connection_pool_mock: mock.Mock):
        # Note here I have changed the called to ConnectionPool
        pymysqlpool.ConnectionPool(
            size=2, maxsize=3, pre_create_num=2, host=os.environ["DATASOURCES_0_HOST"]
        )
```

Note that in the `test_load()` code I have also changed the called to `ConnectionPool` adding the name of the module `pymysqlpool`.

---

**Useful link about the same topic**
[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75766274/patching-in-unit-tests-does-not-work-actual-method-is-being-called) is an other example of the use of `patch()`.

Comment: Interesting.  in addition to the test I also had to change it in my module code itself, I couldn't use the `from` syntax.